# Call another Controller Method from Controller Method

Tags: java, playframework

I have method in controller. And I want to call from first method  another method in same controller (both are RestAPI) But it make

```
public Result make_something_easy(Long Id){
  // Some easy code

  Thread hard_independent_thread = new Thread() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
           make_something_hard(object.id);
           // no result required - just do that like void method 

      }
   };

   hard_independent_thread.start();

   return ok(Json.toJson(object));
}


// You can call this on API separately
public Result make_something_hard(Long Id){
   // Some code
   // 30 second and more... 
   return ok();
}
```

But code 
`make_something_hard(object.id);`

Make this Error. And i dont know why:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: There is no HTTP Context available from here.
 at play.mvc.Http$Context.current(Http.java:57)
 at play.mvc.Controller.request(Controller.java:32)
 at controllers.CompilationLibrariesController$1    
    .run(CompilationLibrariesController.java:360)
```

Comment: Problem is that the thread that is doing the "hard work" is invoked with a different context than the thread that was assigned to handle the request.

Comment: Play uses less Threads but asynchronous Results. Have might want to have a look at https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaAsync.